# where and how to write updatedata event in the correct way

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want to add a listener which listens to updatedata event in my custom component.

I have several ways to do it, but don't know which one is correct:

1. inside config

   config:{
         updatedata:"dataUpdated"
          }, 
   dataUpdated: function() {
             .........
          }

2.

```
config:{
  listeners:{
     updatedata: function(thisComponent, newData, eOpts){
              ..............
     }
  }
}
```

Also, do I need to call something like:
me.updatedata() within the listener function?

Please correct me if something wrong in my code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would wrap `listeners` in `config` when executing `Ext.define`. During `Ext.create`, or in `items` you would place them at the root of passed object (not wrapped in `config`)

Events are explained in details in [Sencha Touch Event Guide](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.2/#!/guide/events)

Comment: Hi Saki,  can a component destroy itself?

Comment: It depends where it is and what component it is. For example, if it is in items of a container and you call container.removeAll() and the container is configured with `autoDestroy:true` (default) then items are destroyed.

Comment: sorry forgot to paste my question link. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058929/how-to-do-a-self-destroy-inside-a-custom-component-in-sencha-touch